# memory management for large image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, deep-learning, dataset

I am trying to train an image classification model using a large dataset of images but I am not able to use the full dataset for training as I am facing a problem with loading it to memory.
Is there a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Have you considered training the model with generator? You can find more on the subject in the documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit
Please note, that you can pass a generator to the `fit` method. I think this would be the best approach.

Another, a little naive approach would be to train model iteratively on batches that you can fit into memory, it was confirmed by François Chollet in the following issue:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4446
("Yes, successive calls to fit will incrementally train the model.")

You can also consider using train_on_batch method:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#train_on_batch

Comment: I used an ImageDatagenerator with fit method and It solved my problem. Thank you for your help!